# How to link php mvc page through href

Tags: php, model-view-controller

How to link PHP MVC page in href?
    In my `href`, I link model class, controller class, and view page but it's show only view page in browser and `model` and `controller` not work, should I call `controller` function. I am confused about that.

Below is my `href` link

```
<a href="../../View/Modules/Security/SubModules/Masters/UserCreationView.php/Model/Model.php/Controller/Controller.php?show_data"><img src="../../public/images/ModuleImages/Security.gif" style="height: 130px; width: 150px;"/></a>
```

This id my controller function,

```
public function Show_data()
  {
    include './Login.php';

    $result= $this->model->Login_Data();
    $result= $this->model->Insert_update_data();
    $result= $this->model->Delete_data();
    $result= $this->model->Search_data();
    }
```

Comment: Which framework you are using?

Comment: i am not using any framework friend, can u suggest which is good framework for hospital information system

Comment: every framework is good. if you are new you can use CI (code ignitor)